# debug cython extension in windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, gdb, mingw, cython

I'm trying to debug a cython extension module. 
I have been following the instructions in http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/debugging.html 
As I'm using windows 7 I can't do a apt-get install to get a debug build of python. 
So when I run cygdb I use python instead of python-dbg

Inside gdb (with python support, ie. gdb-python27.exe)
I can set a break point with cy break module.function
I can run the python script that uses the pyd with cy run 
however, execution doesn't stop at the set breakpoint, and continues until it crashes (that's what I'm trying to debug) producing a traceback
If I do cy step or cy bt or cy list it complains with "No frame is currently selected."

Does anybody know what's going on?
I suspect it maybe I need a python build with debug symbols. If that's the case does anybody know where could I download such a build?

Comment: Could you please add what exactly you typed for ``cy break``? In my experience it was a bit confusing so you might have made a mistake there. And are you trying to break at ``cdef`` function or ``def`` function?

Comment: Hi, I posted this question in cython-users group and got some replies. Check, https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cython-users/aRu1ab9jqKo However, I still didn't find a solution. I use print staments for debuging, which is not ideal.

Comment: Again, please provide EXACT command that you used in debugging in the post.